# Trocar atributos de um Objeto para outro

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, jsp

Na minha aplicação java tenho um objeto declado como `Extrair extrair = new Extrair();`
E eu uso esse objeto e seus atributos para meu servlet. Porém eu preciso passar esse objeto para o .jsp.
No jsp eu uso `extrair = request.getAttribute();`, só que o método request retorna um Object e eu estou atribuindo um Object a um Extrair.

Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Talvez eu não tenha entendido direito a pergunta, mas não seria simplesmente o caso de fazer um *cast*? `extrair = (Extrair)request.getAttribute();`

Comment: Ele não aceita, foi a primeira coisa que tentei. @mgibsonbr

Comment: Não aceita a sintaxe, ou não funciona (i.e. dá um `ClassCastException`)? Pergunto porque até onde eu saiba não há nada no JSP que impeça um código *inline* de fazer um *cast*... Se for o segundo caso, verifique se a forma como você está acrescentando esse objeto no request (creio eu via `setAttribute`) está correta. A propósito, [não está faltando um parâmetro no `getAttribute`?](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tudo indica que você precisa simplesmente fazer um cast (como o @mgibsonbr indicou), no entanto, para garantir que não ocorra um [ClassCastException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) é indicado verificar se a instancia do objeto corresponde à classe que você está usando:

```
Object attribute=request.getAttribute();
if(attribute instanceOf Extrair)
    extrair = attribute;
```